# Reporting Services - SSRS: Cuando exporto a excel, quiero el encabezado de la tabla para todas las paginas

Tags: sql, excel, server, ssrs

Exporto un excell desde el editor de reportes ssrs y en la vista de paginas del encabezado de la tabla no se muestra para todas las paginas.

Reporte ssrs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestra excel exportado y al que le falta el encabezado de la tabla en la segunda pagina
[image: encabezado tabla]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]